# How can i open a PDF from file shared folder - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, adobe

So, I have work on sharepoint for some time now, and I got into a block.
I need to open a pdf from the shared folder, i go the link for that pdf:

```
"file://vrt-gdocdev7/DavWWWRoot/cd/Tramitar/2141_20190502100058.pdf"
```

Now, if I put that exact string in the explorer.exe, he is going to open the exact pdf in the adobe application.

I want this outcome, but in c# code, like this: The user click's in the button and the pdf open in the adobe application.

Anyone could give me some ideia of doing this? I have already tried thinks like:

--  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(testUrl); did not work...`

-- `//OPENS BROWSER//Response.Redirect(uri.AbsoluteUri); not in the adobe application like I want...`

--

```
static void openInExplorer(string path)
{
    string cmd = "explorer.exe";
    string arg =  + path;
    Process.Start(cmd, arg);
}
```

..... and some more and nothing.....